# Expressing Math Equations

Tags: functional-equations, integers, image-processing

I'm confused how to express the following expressions in math equations for publication:

- $x =$ integer part of $y$
- $x =$ fraction part of $y$
- image $x =$ shifted version of image $y$ left with $z$ pixels.
- image $x =$ shifted version of image $y$ up with $z$ pixels.

I thought about this: $x =$ intPart$(y)$ and image$_x =$ shiftLeft$(y, z)$.
But they are programming style more than math equations. Any hints ?

Comment: integer part: $x = [y]$ and fractional part: $x = \{y \}$.. the last two are not math statements

Comment: @George [ or ⌊ ?

Comment: both are the same thing. the first notation was introduced by gauss in some paper and became the standard. the other symbols (that were mentioned in the answer) were introduced by someone later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lfloor y \rfloor $ denotes usually the integer part of $ y $, $\{ y \} $ denotes the fractional part of $ y $ ($\{ y \} =y-\lfloor y \rfloor $). And sorry, but I have no idea what does "image x = shifted version of image y up with z pixels." mean.
And I wouldn't use $[y]$ to represent the integer part of $y$, since it can be easily confused (for example in $[5+(6-1)]=x$, $[y]$ doesn't represent the integer part).

Comment: Thank you for answering half of the question.

Comment: You're welcome, but "image x= shifted version of image y left with z pixels." is definityely not a mathematical statement.

Comment: I think it can be someway. Lets name an image called M, where M_i,j is the value of pixel of row number i and column number j of that M. Like this we can trite everything in math. What do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you represent an image by a matrix, e.g. $ x\in\mathbb {R}^{3x3}$. Then, your upshifted image y is

$y=\left (\begin {matrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end {matrix}\right) x $

However, this assumes padding with zeros, and loss of pixels at the top.

Another solution is simply to define the position of the image's upper left corner by (x, y), and to define $ shiftup ((x, y))=(x, y-1) $...

For the other questions,  I refer to hetajr's answer. ..

Edit: A more general notation, to move an abitrary image $x$ up for $n$ pixels: $\operatorname{shiftup}(x, n)=A_nx$, with the square matrix $A_n=(\delta_{i+n,j})$ and $\delta_{k,l}=1$ if $k=l$, and zero otherwise. If you are lazy, you can then define $\operatorname{shiftleft}(x,n)=\operatorname{shiftup}^T(x^T,n)$

Comment: I don't prefer the second solution. The first solution is good, but can you generalize it for nXm matrix ? Also, the shift is by z pixels and it's not necessarily equal to 1.

Comment: For a shift of z pixels, apply the function z times, or take the z'th power of the shift matrix.

Comment: OK, Thanks. What if the image is not a square matrix ?
Also, if z= 100, matrix multiplication 100 times is much time consuming than what I actually do in my implementation code which is just indexing. What do you think ?

Comment: It does not matter if your image is represented as a square matrix or not. The "shifting" matrix will be square. 
For a mathematical notation it does not matter how "time consuming" a direct one-to-one implementation of the operation is. Nevertheless, I edited the answer such that it would correspond to a less time consuming algorithm when implemented one-to-one in a computer. In the answer, there is already the indication that $A_n$ is a square matrix. I would leave it as a task for the reader to figure out the right dimensions (there is only one obvious answer).